# How can a multi-select-list be edited using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I'd like to edit an object like the one below. I'd like the UsersSelectedList populated with one or more Users from the UsersGrossList.

Using the standard edit-views in mvc, I get only strings and booleans (not shown below) mapped.
Many of the examples I find on google utilizes early releases of the mvc framework whereas I use the official 1.0 release.

Any examples of the view is appreciated.

```
public class NewResultsState
{
    public IList<User> UsersGrossList { get; set; }
    public IList<User> UsersSelectedList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Html.ListBox in combination with IEnumerable SelectListItem

View

```
         <% using (Html.BeginForm("Category", "Home",
      null,
      FormMethod.Post))
       { %>  
        <%= Html.ListBox("CategoriesSelected",Model.CategoryList )%>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="subform" />
        <% }%>
```

Controller/Model:

```
        public List<CategoryInfo> GetCategoryList()
    {
        List<CategoryInfo> categories = new List<CategoryInfo>();
        categories.Add( new CategoryInfo{ Name="Beverages", Key="Beverages"});
        categories.Add( new CategoryInfo{ Name="Food", Key="Food"});
        categories.Add(new CategoryInfo { Name = "Food1", Key = "Food1" });
        categories.Add(new CategoryInfo { Name = "Food2", Key = "Food2" });
        return categories;
    }

    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> CategoriesSelected { get; set; }

    }
    public ActionResult Category(ProductViewModel model )
    {
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoryList =
                                from category in GetCategoryList()
                                select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = category.Name,
                                    Value = category.Key,
                                    Selected = (category.Key.StartsWith("Food"))
                                };
      model.CategoryList = categoryList;

      return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that User model has Id and Name properties:

```
<%= Html.ListBox("users", Model.UsersGrossList.Select(
    x => new SelectListItem {
        Text = x.Name,
        Value = x.Id,
        Selected = Model.UsersSelectedList.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)
    }
) %>
```

Or with View Model

```
public class ViewModel {
    public Model YourModel;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users;
}
```

Controller:

```
var usersGrossList = ...
var model = ...

var viewModel = new ViewModel {
    YourModel = model;
    Users = usersGrossList.Select(
        x => new SelectListItem {
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.Id,
            Selected = model.UsersSelectedList.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<%= Html.ListBox("users", Model.Users ) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

@ eu-ge-ne < thankyou so much for your answer - was having real trouble finding a way to multiselect a list of values from and to model.
Using your code I used the ListBoxFor Html control in my Edit/Update page and passed the whole model back to my controller (including the mulisple selected values) on Save.

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(model => model, Model.UsersGrossList.Select( 
x => new SelectListItem { 
    Text = x.Name, 
    Value = x.Id, 
    Selected = Model.UsersSelectedList.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id) 
}
```

) %>