# Specific ListBox value always selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ListBoxFor where the user can select multiple values ,A user wants that he should get one value always selected 
for ex:

```
ListBox contains:
Id   Category
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    General
```

here General category should always be selected and user should not be able to change this selected value from ListBox.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, ViewBag.ListCategories as MultiSelectList, new { })
```

I am using Asp.Net MVC 5

Actually this is we can say a very rare scenario,One approach i can use is to use some jquery.If anyone has any solution for this in MVC helpers then plz tell me other wise i will be using jquery.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need a listbox at all if you can never change it?

Comment: You are right we can implement it in code, but the client needs it in a listbox, thats the only reason.

Comment: But it should not be  a reason for you to vote down this question

Comment: I downvoted because your question is unclear and does not show research effort. If anything you can just disable the listbox

Comment: I dont know how i can show you my research effort , its not a common scenario that everyone would require. I have tried to be clear but if its still not understandable then you can ask for more explanation. But its not a good thing to just down vote and say 'no research effort'.

Comment: Research effort is not just about what you have searched for, it also involves what you have tried to solve your problem, what didn't work and why it didn't work. Your question doesn't actually ever include a question, just a requirement which is why it is unclear what you are asking. For the record, I (and others) am normally willing to remove my downvote in accordance with a questions quality.

Comment: Have you considered setting the HTML `disabled` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `jquery`

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#SelectedCategory').find('option[value="5"]').attr('selected','selected');
  });
```

This works fine.

Comment: Thanks i will try it ,but , is there anything not available within the html helper listboxfor in mvc.

Comment: This may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995073/how-can-a-multi-select-list-be-edited-using-asp-net-mvc @pro-grammed